npm config error `msvs_version` is not a valid npm option
I'm trying to get a local dev env set up for making contributions to the Vscode repo. As part of the set-up instructions, you're supposed to set a npm config option "msvs_version". Attempting to do so results in an error;
npm error `msvs_version` is not a valid npm option
I've made sure the C++ Desktop Dev options, and Node options are installed via the Visual Studio Installer. Npm is up-to-date for my version of Node. I'm running Windows 11.
I also tried creating the option manually via npm config edit, however it does not preserve it. Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Full error log:
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.7.0
2 info using node@v20.11.0
3 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\npmrc
4 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\Drake\.npmrc
5 silly config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc
6 verbose title npm config set msvs_version 2022
7 verbose argv "config" "set" "msvs_version" "2022"
8 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-02T18_31_23_501Z-
9 verbose logfile C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-02T18_31_23_501Z-debug-0.log
10 info config set "msvs_version" "2022"
11 verbose stack Error: `msvs_version` is not a valid npm option
11 verbose stack     at Config.set (C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\config.js:150:15)
11 verbose stack     at Config.exec (C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\config.js:115:20)
11 verbose stack     at Config.cmdExec (C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\base-cmd.js:138:17)
11 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:92:55
11 verbose stack     at Object.start (C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\proc-log\lib\index.js:101:21)
11 verbose stack     at Npm.exec (C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:92:17)
11 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\entry.js:65:29)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\Drake
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22631
14 verbose node v20.11.0
15 verbose npm  v10.7.0
16 error `msvs_version` is not a valid npm option
17 verbose exit 1
18 verbose code 1
19 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Drake\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-02T18_31_23_501Z-debug-0.log

